# Django rest PUT method to update foreign key data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, put

DRF doc's [say's](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) i need to override serializers `create` and `update` methods to update and/or create nested data. But when i am trying to edit existing `descriptions` my code creates a new one. Is there a simple way to detect which descriptions was edit and update only it?

```
 class TaskSerializer(ModelSerializer):
     url = HyperlinkedIdentityField(
         view_name='tasks:tasks-detail',
         lookup_field='pk',
     )
    author = SlugField(source='author.username')
    executor = SlugField(source='executor.username')
    descriptions = DescriptionSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = (
            'pk',
            'url',
            'title',
            'project',
            'status',
            'author',
            'executor',
            'descriptions'
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        descriptions_data = validated_data.pop('descriptions', None)
        author = validated_data.pop('author', None)
        executor = validated_data.pop('executor', None)
        try:
            task_author = User.objects.get(username=author['username'])
            task_executor = User.objects.get(username=executor['username'])
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise ValidationError(
                 _("Такого пользователя не сущетсвует!"))

        task = Task.objects.create(author=task_author, executor=task_executor, **validated_data)
        if descriptions_data:
            for description in descriptions_data:
                description, created = Description.objects.get_or_create(
                     text=description['text'],
                     task=task
                )
                task.descriptions.add(description)
        return task

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        descriptions_data = validated_data.pop('descriptions', None)
        instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
        instance.project = validated_data.get('project', instance.project)
        instance.status = validated_data.get('status', instance.status)
        author = validated_data.pop('author', None)
        executor = validated_data.pop('executor', None)
        try:
            if author:
                task_author = User.objects.get(username=author['username'])
                instance.author = task_author
            if executor:
                task_executor = User.objects.get(username=executor['username'])
                 instance.executor = task_executor
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise ValidationError(
                _("Такого пользователя не сущетсвует!"))

        descriptions_list = []
        if descriptions_data:
            for description in descriptions_data:
                description, created = Description.objects.get_or_create(
                    text=description["text"],
                    task=instance
                )
                descriptions_list.append(description)

        instance.descriptions.set(descriptions_list)
        instance.save()
        return instance


class DescriptionSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Description
        fields = (
            'pk',
            'text',
        )

class Task(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (1, _("В процессе разработки")),
        (2, _("В процессе тестирования")),
        (3, _("На ревью")),
        (4, _("Открыта")),
        (5, _("Закрыта"))
    )
    title = models.CharField(_('Название'), max_length=60)
    project = models.CharField(_('Название проекта'), max_length=60)
    status = models.IntegerField(_('Статус'), choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                                 default=4)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                               max_length=60, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='author',
                               verbose_name=_('Автор'),
                               validators=[validate_user])
    executor = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                 max_length=60, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 related_name='executor',
                                 verbose_name=_('Исполнитель'),
                                 validators=[validate_user])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{}'.format(self.title)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Задача')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Задачи')


class Description(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='descriptions')
    text = models.TextField(_('Описание'))

    def __str__(self):
        return '#{}'.format(self.pk)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'#{}'.format(self.pk)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Описание')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Описания')
```

Comment: You want to edit description or task model data ?

Comment: @SHIVAMJINDAL Both. But editing of task model data works fine.

Comment: In `update()` in your serializer, you're loading descriptions by text and task, but if the incoming text is different (because you've edited it), then a new description will get created for the task. Rather than `Description.objects.get_or_create()` it may be better to load the description by its id, then set the text, and then save it.

Comment: @WillKeeling Yeah, i think this way, but i don't recieve in request description id(because it's read only i think). Is there a way to recieve it?

Comment: It looks like it may be serialized as `pk` - according to the `DescriptionSerializer`. Do you have access to that in `descriptions_data`?

Comment: @WillKeeling I do not.

Comment: Are you able to modify the client request so that the `pk` is transmitted?

Comment: @WillKeeling i trying to do that, but if i send a json with `pk` key`(DescriptionSerializer have a `pk` in `fields`) but it disappear in update method. Maybe because it's read only field?